# Page main content not showing up on Chrome until after clicking on the inspect elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The page content in #main area is not showing up only on Chrome browser. But I can see the code is there when I view the page source. And when I click on the "inspect elements" or by clicking on any CSS style on the "inspect elements" popup, the content can just appear suddenly. Here is the page URL you can take a look on Chrome browser,

http://ssf-qa.uchicago.edu/Home.html

The version of the Chrome I'm using is,
Version 33.0.1750.146 m

And we have custom fonts on the page.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this recently with Modernizr, which I see you have running on there too. If you remove the reference to modernizr it works right away!  I think we just have to wait for a bug fix.

Comment: Yes. Removed the reference to the Modernizr resolves the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: But there are some other libraries are using the methods in Modernizr, so It seems i can't just simply remove it.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks JConnell!